# Re-fetching data in React with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm hoping someone can help me with an issue i have encountered with re-fetching data. On the initial page render I'm fetching data which displays information about a random movie, and then when the user hits the "next" button on my page a new random movie is then displayed. The issue i'm experiencing is that it seems to be re-fetching the data twice and by that I'm mean that when the button is clicked once, a new movie pops up for a split second followed by another straight after.

After hours of googling I can't seem to find an exact solution to this problem but i suspect it's in the way that I'm using the useEffect hook:

```
    const Movie = () => {
     const [pageNo, setPageNo] = useState(1);
 const [movieNo, setMovieNo] = useState(1);
 const [movie, setMovie] = useState('');
 const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
 const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState('https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/');

 function handleClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setMovieNo(Math.floor(Math.random() * 20));
  setPageNo(Math.floor(Math.random() * 500 + 1));
 }

 async function fetchData(page) {
  const result = await axios(
   `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=a035c9128c767a8b70c9413632d63cd0&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=${page}&vote_average.gte=1.0`
  );
  setMovie(result.data.results);
  setIsLoading(false);
 }

 useEffect(() => {
  fetchData(pageNo);
 }, [pageNo]);
    
     return (
      ...
     );
    };
```

Sorry if this question isn't very clear, I've have never been too great at explaining issues

Comment: The next button make a request to get another 20 movies and it executes only once [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-wright-mmdfv?file=/src/Movie.js), I don't see how this can cause the issue you encountere. how are you displaying the movie data ?

Comment: @ⵍⵢⴻⵙ I am passing down movieNo as a prop to another component. So given that movieNo is a random number between 1-20 then I use that to access the movie array at a random index, which then displays the data: this is a sample of what i have <MovieCard
    movie={movie}
    isLoading={isLoading}
    url={imageUrl}
    size={'w342'}
    movieNum={rank.movieNo}
   />  which then passes onto the next component : <MovieTitle>{movie[movieNum].original_title}</MovieTitle>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is in this function.
Changing state twice (one each for movieNo , pageNo) causes the page to render twice.

```
 function handleClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setMovieNo(Math.floor(Math.random() * 20));
  setPageNo(Math.floor(Math.random() * 500 + 1));
 }
```

Complete Sample Code to reproduce problem

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Movie = () => {
  const [pageNo, setPageNo] = useState(1);
  const [movieNo, setMovieNo] = useState(1);
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/");

  function handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setMovieNo(Math.floor(Math.random() * 20));
    setPageNo(Math.floor(Math.random() * 500 + 1));
  }

  async function fetchData(page) {
    const result = await axios(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=a035c9128c767a8b70c9413632d63cd0&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=${page}&vote_average.gte=1.0`
    );
    setMovie(result.data.results);
    setIsLoading(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(pageNo);
  }, [pageNo]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{isLoading ? "" : movie[movieNo].title}</p>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>next</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Movie;
```

**FIX HERE**

1. Combined state in single object

```
 const [rank, setRank] = useState({ pageNo: 1, movieNo: 1 });
```

```
  setRank({
      pageNo: Math.floor(Math.random() * 500 + 1),
      movieNo: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)
    });
```

Complete code after fix.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Movie = () => {
  const [rank, setRank] = useState({ pageNo: 1, movieNo: 1 });
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/");

  function handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setRank({
      pageNo: Math.floor(Math.random() * 500 + 1),
      movieNo: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)
    });
  }

  async function fetchData(page) {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const result = await axios(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=a035c9128c767a8b70c9413632d63cd0&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=${page}&vote_average.gte=1.0`
    );
    setMovie(result.data.results);
    setIsLoading(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(rank.pageNo);
  }, [rank]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{isLoading ? "loading..." : movie[rank.movieNo].title}</p>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>next</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Movie;
```

In summary, there is nothing wrong with useEffect.
Changing state too many times is causing your component to render many times. Try to merge all these conditions in a single state so that its easier to manage.